# Touch screen for 10 sec then show result

Tags: android

How we can set screen like that if we touch particular button or anything on screen after 10 sec they show result like I touch button for 10 sec then intent works and move to next one

Comment: Help others to help you. Read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Edit your post, and show the code that you are working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

steps:

1. use ontouchlistener
2. start a timer of 10 sec
3. When you press action down will trigger.
4. if user remove the finger, action up will trigger.
5. Track your timer if i remove finger within 10 sec, don't perform your action otherwise DO YOUR OPERATION.